# What is the best way for search query?

Tags: android, sqlite, indexing, query-optimization, inner-join

I have big SQLite database(45MB). I take data from different tables using INNER JOIN. However, it is working very slow. Maybe it is up to mobile phone which I am testing(Samsung Galaxy Ace). What should be done in order to make query very fast? 
a)creating an index for tables
b)creating new table which will include tables I need
c)other way you reccomend

[image]

I am taking tables:entry, r_ele, k_ele, sense, gloss with JOIN.

```
query = "SELECT" + " e.id AS _id," + " ke.id AS ke_id,"
                + " ke.fk as ke_fk," + " ke.value as ke_value,"
                + " re.id AS ke_id," + " re.fk as re_fk,"
                + " re.value as re_value," + " s.id AS  s_id,"
                + " s.fk as s_fk," + " g.id AS g_id," + " g.fk as g_fk,"
                + " g.lang," + " g.value as g_value" + " FROM entry e"
                + "     INNER JOIN k_ele ke ON e.id = ke.fk"
                + "     INNER JOIN r_ele re ON e.id = re.fk"
                + "     INNER JOIN sense s ON e.id = s.fk"
                + "     INNER JOIN gloss g ON s.id = g.fk"
                + " WHERE g.lang IS NULL AND g.value like '"
                + lookingFor + "%'  GROUP BY g.value LIMIT 5 ";
```

Comment: Please post table structures and query so that we can help.

Comment: Added table structure...

Comment: Do you have any indexes or primary key/unique constraints?

Comment: Do you have an index on gloss(value) ?    Or, better still, gloss(value, lang, fk, id)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a big database and doing so many joins on the fly, the performance is bound to be slow. I had a similar issue. The way I resolved it is by creating temporary table with the required columns by joining the respective tables at the time of app initialization.

In case your data is dynamic, you need to update the data in the temporary table as well when required. But if the size of the changed data is not so big, updating will not really create any performance issue.

The benefit of creating of temporary table is that the longer operation is there only once and it is in the startup.